# What kind of program is Persephone?

Tags: the-matrix

In an earlier question we've discussed [what kind of program the Merovingian is](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52289/what-kind-of-program-is-the-merovingian?rq=1) and it's widely agreed that he's an operating system to an earlier version of the matrix - a predecessor to the Oracle.

Persephone, however, is his long suffering companion and lover. They have apparently been together for some time.

> Persephone: A long time ago, when we first came here, it was so different.

**Do we have any information on what sort of program she was?** From the scene in the bathroom with Neo my guess is that she's something to do with human emotion, maybe even love... but I'm extremely curious if anyone else has worked out anything else.

Comment: Updated the quote to match what was in the original answer because I think it's relevant and made it clearer who is saying it.

Comment: I can't back it up but I think she's an older intuitive program, possibly even the one who we're told in The Matrix came up with the choice that kept humans in the system. It matches her predictive abilities and her ability to read people's, and programs', intentions.

Comment: @Ash No, the "intuitive program" you are talking about is the Oracle.

Comment: @Null It never actually **says** that, it's just assumed that that's who the Architect is talking about but he doesn't say the Oracle. The Architect just says "an intuitive program", and in fact he scoffs when Neo suggests the Oracle as the source.

Comment: @Ash The Architect scoffs at Neo's use of "the Oracle" as her name, not at his suggestion that the program we call the Oracle is the intuitive program in question. If Persephone's "predictive abilities and her ability to read people's, and programs', intentions" is evidence that she created the choice system then the same evidence points all the more so to the Oracle, whose predictive abilities are far better than Persephone's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80554/discussion-between-null-and-ash).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there vampires and werewolves and aliens in the Matrix?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11624/are-there-vampires-and-werewolves-and-aliens-in-the-matrix). Persephone's described as a vampire by her character's actor.

Comment: @Valorum I've just found [this related Q&A from Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/146), which says "_The DVD Behind the scenes mentions that she is a vampire that seeks after emotions_" (although I don't have access to that source so cannot confirm that myself). It does indeed seem that she is likely a vampire.

Answer (score 2):

She was probably an anomaly hunter.

> My husband saved them because they were notoriously difficult to terminate. How many people keep silver bullets in their gun?

Considering the fact that Persephone killed one of the anomalies coming from the much older version of the Matrix, namely the werewolf Abel, with a single shot, they were not that difficult to terminate, at least to Persephone.

Moreover, by stating that not many people carry silver bullets, she accentuates on the fact that not many people know how to terminate such anomalies or not many people are able to do so.

Comment: Very interesting thought. However, considering she knows her faithless husband employs such beings she might have prepared some countermeasures against them just in case.

Comment: @SeanCondon True, But also, she might have helped his husband acquire those anomalies.

Comment: Finding anomalies and helping to sequester them sounds like an anti-virus program.